# why cdn links put in the bottom of index file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why we put CDN links for AngularJS file in last of index page. I put it top of the file but it working well. Is there big difference between these two.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Why-put-script-tag-below-html

Answer (score 0):

It improve the performance and allow your DOM to be rendered.If you put your CDN on top your it could be that your page rendering will stop at some point because you're downloading the javascript files from CDN..

This way the content will load faster.

Comment: Is html file loaded top to bottom synchronous way or asynchronous way?

Comment: Generally top to bottom in synchronous way.

Comment: It means here first all content is loaded from page and then in last all java script file is loaded. Thanks  Squiroid

Comment: yes exactly DOM rendering should not disturb for loading javascript files :)

Comment: But i see css files are always put inside the header section of page.........can we put it also in the bottom of the page

Comment: No css files should place at the top because it will provide style to you DOM elements and it should render before DOM rendering :)